# How to search for a Xml node with a given attribute value in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have this XML file and I want to get the country nodes which have the pattern 'in' in their name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I have tried this

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    list=root.find(".//country[contains(@name, 'Pana')]")
```

But I am getting an error : SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Could anyone please help how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` provides only *limited support for XPath expressions for locating elements in a tree*, and that doesn't include xpath `contains()` function. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) for list of supported xpath syntax.

You need to resort to a library that provide better xpath support, like [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html), or use simpler xpath and do further filtering manually, for example :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
list = filter(lambda x: 'Pana' in x.get('name'), root.findall(".//country[@name]"))
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution you have provided is working. Is there a way to do a case-insensitive search also?

Comment: @AbhishekMoondra you can change the `lambda` to convert attribute value to lower before comparing : `lambda x: 'pana' in x.get('name').lower()`. That will result in case-insensitive search..

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on why your original code does not work, but is has nothing to do with the XPath expression. The expression is fine, except for the leading `.` which you can safely omit.

Any reason you are not using the [lxml xpath() method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method)?

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('etree.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
list = root.xpath("//country[contains(@name,'Pana')]")

print list[0].tag
```

gives back a `country` element:

```
$ python test.py
country
```

Answer (score 0):

The xml parser you are using does not support `contains`. You will need to use a different parser for full xpath support

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath